# Apply height and width of one image to others with JavaScript .getBoundingClientRect

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm trying to take the width and height of the first image and apply this to all subsequent images.

So far I have managed to apply the width and height of the first image to the second image, but not to the third, fourth etc...

I'm very new to JavaScript so am probably making a silly mistake.

Please see the current situation here. https://codepen.io/GBol/pen/GRXWvJY

```
<div class="boxA">   
  <img class="landscape"src="http://placekitten.com/800/400">
</div>

<div class="boxB">   
  <img class="portrait"src="http://placekitten.com/400/800">
</div>

<div class="boxB">   
  <img class="portrait"src="http://placekitten.com/400/800">
</div>






.boxA {
  width: 20%;
  border: solid blue;
  display: block;
  float: left;
 }

.boxB {
 border: solid blue;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 }

.landscape {
width: 100%;
display: block;
} 

.portrait {
height: 100%;
/** to center horizontally **/
margin: auto;
display: block;
}






var boxA = document.querySelector(".boxA"),
boxB = document.querySelector(".boxB")

function copyHeight(from,to){
to.style.height = from.getBoundingClientRect().height + "px"
}
copyHeight(boxA,boxB)

function copyWidth(from,to){
to.style.width = from.getBoundingClientRect().width + "px"
}
copyWidth(boxA,boxB)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `querySelector` method returns just one element.  If there are multiple matching elements, it'll just return the first.

So if you want to run the function for all the elements on your page with the class of `boxB`, then the first thing you need to do is select them all with `querySelectorAll`.

Next, you'll need to use a loop of some kind to run the function for each of the elements that were selected.  A nice compact way of doing that is with [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

The `forEach` method takes as an argument a single function that you want to run for every element in your array/set/nodelist.  This function will be passed each element as parameter so that you can reference it in your function. You could write that function like this:

```js
function(box) {
  copyHeight(boxA,box)
  copyWidth(boxA,box)
}
```

but it's a little easier to read when written using the "fat arrow" syntax:

```js
(box) => {
  copyHeight(boxA,box)
  copyWidth(boxA,box)
}
```

Altogether, the final code could look like this:

```js
const boxA = document.querySelector(".boxA")
const boxB = document.querySelectorAll(".boxB")

boxB.forEach((box) => {
  copyHeight(boxA, box)
  copyWidth(boxA, box)
})
    
function copyHeight(from, to){
  to.style.height = from.getBoundingClientRect().height + "px"
}


function copyWidth(from, to){
  to.style.width = from.getBoundingClientRect().width + "px"
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for this. That's a really helpful, clear explanation!